# can't solve 'date' validation with 'max', 'min' properties Yii2

Tags: yii2

I can't understand - function returning string (verified by var_dump()):

```
['userBirthDate', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 
'max' => function() {
    $date = new DateTime();
    date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('12 years'));
    $maxDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
    return $maxDate;
},
'min' => function() {
    $date = new DateTime();
    date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('100 years'));
    $minDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
    return $minDate;
}
```

],

but I have the mistake:
"Object of class Closure could not be converted to string".

[image: mistake code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validators `max` and `min` can only accept a number, not an anonymous function, that's why you are getting the error.

Try this code, which creates a new validator called `validateUserBirthDate`, as well as using the existing `date` validator.

```
[
    ['userBirthDate'], 
    'validateUserBirthDate'
],
[
    ['userBirthDate'],
    'date', 'format' =>  'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
]
```

then in your model add a custom validator;

```
public function validateUserBirthDate($attribute, $params) {
$date = new \DateTime();
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('12 years'));
$minAgeDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('100 years'));
$maxAgeDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
    if ($this->$attribute > $minAgeDate) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Date is too small.');
    } elseif ($this->$attribute < $maxAgeDate) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Date is to big.');
    }}
```

Comment: very good idea - thank you! I post the final code here - yours has some mistakes.

Comment: Thanks @KirylLapchynski, I've amended my answer accordingly. Would you be so kind as to accept the answer?

Comment: 1@JoeMiller - yes of course! You spend the time for me.